# ViewContainerRef not loading component into DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: `
  <div #target></div>
  `
})
export class MyCmp {
@ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target : ViewContainerRef;

render() {
    let cmp = Component(metadata)(type);
    this.componentResolver.resolveComponent(cmp).then(factory => {
      let component = this.target.createComponent(factory, 0, null, null);
    });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to load component into a `ViewContainerRef`. All [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html) says that once the component is created, it is automatically loaded into the DOM (where the `ViewChild` is.) But this isnt happening. Why? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the code you have added is complete or just part of it, I do not see ComponentResolver injected into your constructor, also it may be typo here but `resolveComponent` then block is not closed (missing `)`).

```
 import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentResolver }  from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'my-test',
   template: `
    Test Component
   `
 })
 export class TestComponent {}

 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `<h3 class="title">Basic Angular 2</h3>
   <div #target></div>
   `
 })
 export class AppComponent {
   @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target : ViewContainerRef;

   constructor(private componentResolver: ComponentResolver){
     this.render();
   }

   render = () =>  {
     // include app specific logic to get ComponentType
     //  let cmp = Component(metadata)(type);
     this.componentResolver.resolveComponent(TestComponent).then(factory => {
      let component = this.target.createComponent(factory, 0, null, null);
     });
    }
  }
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/95gSc4MNXWv2cq4fSjmT?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: in my source i have all typos corrected haha. My example above is not complete because the complete version is much longer. Unfortunately I'm still having this problem...

Comment: Did you check the plunker? Can you create a plunker for your code are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Dynamicaly Add Elements</h2>
      <button (click)="addItem()">add hello</button>
      <div #placeholder></div>
    </div>
  `,
  entryComponents: [HelloComponent]
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('placeholder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef;
  private componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any>;

  constructor(componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, compiler: Compiler) {
    this.componentFactory = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
    //this.componentFactory = compiler.compileComponentSync(HelloComponent);
  }

  addItem () {
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory, 0);
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3dzkMVXe4AGSRhk11TXG?p=preview)